# Is there a way to not redownload images everytime a user opens the app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on a tableView that shows images and it is re-downloading the images every time the view loads. Is there a way to cache the images so it only downloads the images once? (Cache the images)

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: you can use  the NSCache to make the image requests and avoid re-downloading or do you mean a Firebase SDK  function?

Comment: Yea I was wondering if there was a Firebase SDK function. I'll take a look at NSCache though.

Comment: We're hoping to eventually add a built in cache for Firebase Storage, as this is definitely a very nice to have feature. In the mean time, `NSCache` will be your friend :)

Comment: Thanks, I found that currently Kingfisher on github was most effective with caching images and loading async on table views. Check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

In your tableViewDelegate create a Cache object

```
var myCache = NSCache()
```

Then in the rowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let row = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as? MyCell{


        //Get the item
        let item = items[indexPath.row]

        //You need to cancel previous requests and reset the image to avoid render errors caused by the reusable row
        //here you should also cancel any previous requests made to avoid downloading an image that the user won't see because he scrolled 
        cell.img.image = nil

        //Search for the image in the cache
        var img:UIImage?
        img = myCache.objectForKey(item.image_url) as? UIImage

        row.configureCell( item: item,img:img)

        return row

    }else{
        return MyCell()
    }
}
```

And finally in the cell

```
func configureCell(item:Item,image:UIImage?){
    self.item = item


    if image != nil{
        //The image exist so you assign it to your UIImageView
        img.image = image
    }else{
        //Create the request to download the image
    }

}
```